# Getting 401 Unauthorized on Cloud Run when using end-user authentication

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

Following the authentication guide for Cloud Run [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/overview), I wanted to make a service only accessible by authenticated users.

I created a base service, called helloworld (yes, no originality here), and applied the following policy:

```sh
gcloud run services add-iam-policy-binding helloworld \
    --member="allAuthenticatedUsers" \
    --role="roles/run.invoker"
```

I then tried to invoke it using the `gcloud auth print-identity-token` ID Token like this:

```sh
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)" https://helloworld-*****.a.run.app
```

All good, the service responds with bearer tokens coming from a @gmail.com account and a GSuite one using `gcloud`.

As a next step, I followed the end-user authentication guide [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/end-users) and:

- created web application credentials in the same project as the Cloud Run service above
- redeployed the service to absorb the new Client ID configuration
- created a simple HTML page with that Client ID and Google Sign-In logic (like [this one](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/?_ga=2.219561434.235679828.1581411032-2097152760.1581411019))
- run a local webserver to serve that page and got a new ID Token
- attempted to do the same `curl` with that very token

This time though, the response was a 401 with the following value in the `WWW-Authenticate` header:

```
Bearer error="invalid_token" error_description="The access token could not be verified"
```

This is the response of the https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo API:

```
{
  "iss": "accounts.google.com",
  "azp": "*****************.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "aud": "*****************.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "sub": "*******",
  "email": "theuser@gmail.com",
  "email_verified": "true",
  "at_hash": "********",
  "name": "********",
  "picture": "********",
  "given_name": "********",
  "family_name": "********",
  "locale": "en",
  "iat": "1581617530",
  "exp": "1581621130",
  "jti": "6a0dd7561c0d95f7c92fc29a885039fe3f23db16",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "kid": "d8efea1f66e87bb36c2ea09d837338bdd810353b",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
```

and the `azp` and `aud` values are the same Client ID that is defined as a Web Application credential in the project.

I also tried to add the specific user to the service like this:

```sh
gcloud run services add-iam-policy-binding helloworld \
    --member="user:theuser@gmail.com" \
    --role="roles/run.invoker"
```

Still no luck... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, could you help confirm: 1) the client_id comes from the same project of the cloud run service? ; 2) the token generated was not expired? ("exp" claim); 3) when you use curl, use: curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <id_token>"  <URL>

Comment: Hi @wlhee, yes, I confirm that the Client ID was generated in the same project that's hosting the Cloud Run service; also, the token retrieved using the HTML page was used within minutes with the curl command as you specified it (Authorization: Bearer <token>).

Comment: can you share your project id and cloud run service name with me?

Comment: Sure, here they are:

`363397985288-7a7e83ssimq8t0tvolqaha161u9tdckh.apps.googleusercontent.com`
`https://helloworld-r4v55jcbxa-ew.a.run.app`. I also created another project, client ID and service just in case...
`788273985948-min8mv0jk4sldbaha096avgv034jr32o.apps.googleusercontent.com`
`https://helloworld-2pr4qhpiyq-ew.a.run.app`

Comment: Thanks. I checked both cloud run services, the oauth client IDs were not populated. We did have an issue earlier this week, but we believe it got fixed on Wednesday PST. Did you deploy these two cloud run services after Wednesday?

Comment: No, the first deployment of the services was on the 10th of Feb, the last on the 12th: I now made a new revision and it's working perfectly. Thank you very much for your help and support!

Comment: Awesome! Sorry for the inconvenience!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to wlhee's input about the issue, I redeployed the service and was able to successfully access it with a token generated using the Client ID from the same project.